# Why doesn't this GROUP BY query work?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm querying my Access table with this query:

```
SELECT (VIN&' '&Make&' '&Model&' '&CarYear&' '&ExColor&' '&InColor&' ')as CarDescript
        FROM TestTable
        WHERE (WorkOrderNumber='$workorder')
        GROUP BY AssignedEmp;
```

But a similar type of query works just fine in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6f69e/2)

Even if I replace the long (VIN&' '&....) with VIN it still doesn't work.

EDIT: Schema of the table is

WorkOrderNumber - Priority - JobStage - WorkItem - AssignedEmp - DueDate - VIN - Make - ... - InColor

Comment: Could you, please, show us your table schema?

Comment: It looks like you have syntax errors, `AssignedEmp"`?

Comment: There is an extra double quote in your GROUP BY clause

Comment: On what SQL server are you executing this? And Note: not using named group by can cause bad results..

Comment: Sorry that's not a syntax error, I copy pasted this from a PHP file where it is $sql = "SELECT...."; and I accidentally included the extra "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general use `+` instead of `&` for SQL.  (Access will allow this however).

In a group by you need to pick which one in the group to use (if you are using mysql like your example it just picks a random one, see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc7d/2)) so to fix this in the general case for your example:

```
SELECT (max(VIN) + ' ' + max(Make) + ' ' + max(Model) + ' ' + max(CarYear) + ' ' + max(ExColor) + ' ' + max(InColor) + ' ')
       as CarDescript
FROM TestTable
WHERE WorkOrderNumber='$workorder'
GROUP BY AssignedEmp;
```

Comment: In Access SQL, either `&` or `+` can be used for concatenation.